# Has the map $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ an antipodal point with the same image?

Tags: general-topology

The problem says that if $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous, then there exists a point $q\in S^2 $ such that $f(q)=f(-q)$.

I don't know how to prove it. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The B-U Theorem is hard to prove in dimension $2$ and greater, but simple in dimension $1$.  Here's how to get your result using the dimension $1$ version.

**Borsuk-Ulam, $1$-dim:**  If $g: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then there is a point $x_0 \in S^1$ with $g(x_0) = g(-x_0)$.

*Proof:*  Suppose not, so that $g(x) \neq g(-x)$ for all $x$.   Define $h: S^1 \to \{\pm 1\}$ by the formula
$$
h(x) = \frac{g(x)-g(-x)}{|g(x)-g(-x)|}.
$$
This is well-defined because the bottom is never $0$.  Moreover, $h$ is clearly continuous and onto, but this contradicts the connectedness of $S^1$.  $\Box$

For your problem, embed $S^1$ into $S^2$ by the equator by the inclusion $i: S^1 \to S^2$.  Now apply the above theorem to $g=f \circ i$ where $f$ is your map $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your argument works for any connected subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ with the property $X = - X$, e.g. for $S^2 \subset   \mathbb{R}^3$. If $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with $g(x) \ne g(-x)$ for all $x \in X$, then your function $h : X \to \{ \pm 1\}$ is well-defined and onto because $h(-x) = -h(x)$.

Comment: Interesting point.  Never thought of it that way.

Comment: Here is an even more general result: Let $X$ be connected with a continuous involution $\iota : X \to X$. Then for each continuous $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $g(x) = g(\iota(x))$. Example: $X = GL_+(n,\mathbb{R})$, $\iota(A) = A^{-1}$.

Comment: Variant of proof: Define $h : X \to \mathbb{R}, h(x) = g(x) - g(\iota(x))$. Then $J = h(X)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a (bounded or unbounded)  interval. Moreover $-J = J$ because $- h(x) = h(\iota(x))$. This is only possible when $0 \in J$.

Comment: At this point you  should just write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a direct consequence of [the Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem). Apply it to

$$g:S^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$$
$$g(v)=\big(f(v), 0\big)$$

Answer (score 1):

When I read Randall's elegant and short proof, I realized that we can easily prove the follwing more general result:

Let $X$ be a nonempty connected topological space with a continuous involution $\iota : X \to X$ (which means that $\iota \circ \iota = id_X$). Then for any continuous $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a point $x \in X$ such that $g(\iota(x)) = g(x)$.

We may apply this to $X = S^n$ and $\iota(x) = -x$.

Define $h : X \to \mathbb{R}, h(x) = g(\iota(x)) - g(x)$. This is a continuous map such that $h(\iota(x)) = -h(x)$ for all $x \in X$. We conclude

$(1) \phantom{.}$ If $y \in h(X)$, then also $-y \in h(X)$.

Define $U = h(X) \cap (-\infty,0)$ and $V = h(X) \cap (0,\infty)$. These are open subsets of $h(X)$ and $(1)$ implies

$(2) \phantom{.}$ If $h(X) \ne \{ 0 \}$, then $U, V \ne \emptyset$.

Assume $0 \notin h(X)$. Then $h(X) = U \cup V$ and $U, V \ne \emptyset$ by $(2)$. Therefore $h(X)$ is not connected which contradicts the fact that continuous images of connected spaces **are** connected.

Therefore $0 \in h(X)$ which proves the assertion.